# using mail() with no access to php.ini

Tags: php

Basically I want to send e-mail from my website but I have a big problem:
my provider don't let me access the php.ini file is there any other way to setup parameters for the `mail()` function?

Comment: What do you mean with "is there any other way to setup parameters for the `mail()` function?"

Comment: http://php.net/ini_set

Comment: @MarcB Are you sure that this will reliably work?

Comment: No, but if you can't change the .ini contents, you can try overriding them later. but that may have been locked down as well, so your only alternative them will be NOT use `mail()` and use something better, like PHPMailer or Swiftmailer. php's `mail()` function is a moronic braindead piece of crap. useable only as a last resort.

Comment: @MarcB just wanted to hear that ;).. Was afraid that I'm missing something

Comment: You can always switch providers too. a simple VPS system is very cheap to rent these days, and you'll have total control over it.

Comment: @MarcB: Have to agree with this one 100%. If this website generates any kind of income for you, there's no need to scrimp on web services. A VPS will usually give you much better performance as well because you're not having to share resources with god knows how many other sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP mailer is what I use: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

I think it is probably more effective, efficient and provides more functionality than normal php `mail` does anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can always go the route of a web service as well. Amazon offers a nifty service that is free: [Amazon SNS](http://aws.amazon.com/sns/)