# Confirmation email not sending

Tags: php, email, admin, activation

so i have this code.
It is for a site that when an admin approves you to be an user he clicks this link. It wil set the account to active, but I also want is to send an email.

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
require('includes/config.php');

//collect values from the url
$memberID = trim($_GET['x']);
$active = trim($_GET['y']);

//if id is number and the active token is not empty carry on
if(is_numeric($memberID) && !empty($active)){

//update users record set the active column to Yes where the memberID and active value match the ones provided in the array
$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE members SET active = 'Yes' WHERE memberID = :memberID AND active = :active");
$stmt->execute(array(
    ':memberID' => $memberID,
    ':active' => $active,
));

//if the row was updated redirect the user
if($stmt->rowCount() == 1){
//redirect to login page
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT email FROM members WHERE memberID = :memberID");
$stmt->bindparam(':memberID', $memberID);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
//send email
    $to = $result->email;
    $subject = "account actief";
    $body = "Uw account op http://www.nol-groningen.nl is actief \n\n
    Met Vriendelijke groet,\n\n
    Website Admin";
    $additionalheaders = "From: <".SITEEMAIL.">\r\n";
    $additionalheaders .= "Reply-To: $".SITEEMAIL."";
    mail($to, $subject, $body, $additionalheaders);

header('Location: login.php?action=active');
exit;

} else {
echo "Your account could not be activated."; 
}

}
?>
```

It did work before i put the email stuff in, now it just goes to a blank page. Does anyone know how i can fix it and let it send an confirmation email?

Comment: looks like a blacklist matter

Comment: Try to echo $email; check weather there is some mail or not in variable.

Answer (score 2):

You are redirecting page before the email code runs so

move `header('Location: login.php?action=active');` down and place it before `exit;`

```
 header('Location: login.php?action=active');
 exit;
```

change your if statement like this

```
if($stmt->rowCount() == 1){
    //redirect to login page
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT email FROM members WHERE memberID = :memberID");
    $stmt->bindparam(':memberID', $memberID);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    //send email
        $to = $result->email;
        $subject = "account actief";
        $body = "Uw account op http://www.nol-groningen.nl is actief \n\n
        Met Vriendelijke groet,\n\n
        Website Admin";
        $additionalheaders = "From: <".SITEEMAIL.">\r\n";
        $additionalheaders .= "Reply-To: $".SITEEMAIL."";
        mail($to, $subject, $body, $additionalheaders);

    header('Location: login.php?action=active');
    exit;

} else {
    echo "Your account could not be activated."; 
}
```

Comment: I have updated my answer check it now and make sure that you are getting memberID on the page.

Comment: Does work on the activation part. Does not work on the mailing part

Answer (score 0):

Aren't there a PHP error in :

```php
$stmt->execute(array(
':email' => $email,

//send email
    $to = $email;
    $subject = "account actief";
    $body = "Uw account op http://www.nol-groningen.nl is actief \n\n
    [...]
));
```

Shouldn't you check for the answer and send email out of the execute ?

Comment: I saw that it didn't work. it send me via the beta folder that does work. so this code doesn't actually work

Comment: Ok, because I tested the codes separately it worked on my servers. Should be the mail server configuration.

Comment: Have you access to your server php.ini ?
if not check for the thread : [using-mail-with-no-access-to-php-ini](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19302079/using-mail-with-no-access-to-php-ini)

Comment: no, I don't. At least I don't know how i can find it

Answer (score 0):

> There are a variety of reasons your script appears to not be sending emails. It's difficult to diagnose these things unless there is an obvious syntax error. Without one you need to run through the checklist below to find any potential pitfalls you may be encountering.

[answered Jul 9 at 2:21 by
John Conde](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24644450/4170669)